# Using a text column in gnuplot as a paramter for plotting

Tags: gnuplot

I am using a csv file containing 3 columns with data as follows:

```
Country name, Year, Population value
Afghanistan, 2000, 8774440
Afghanistan, 2001, 8774441
Afghanistan, 2002, 8774442
Germany, 2000, 18774440
Germany, 2001, 18774442
Germany, 2002, 18774444
```

I am attempting to plot the population growth , i.e year as x axis and the values as y axis

I am new to gnuplot and was wondering if it is possible to plot the 2nd and 3rd columns using the first
column's value as an argument/parameter

I know it is possible to plot particular rows using sed like

```
plot "<(sed -n '0,2p' p.csv)" using 2:3 with lines
```

but this only works when hard coded into my script

I have attempted using awk to get it working but to no avail

```
plot " <(awk '{$1=='Afghanistan'}' p.csv" using 3:4 with lines
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for sed or awk. You can use the ternary operator as filter (see `help ternary`). There should be similar questions around (about filtering by numbers), however, which I can't find right now.

**Code:**

```
### plot data filtered with ternary operator
reset session

set datafile separator comma

$Data <<EOD
Afghanistan, 2000, 8774440
Afghanistan, 2001, 8774441
Afghanistan, 2002, 8774442
Germany, 2000, 18774440
Germany, 2001, 18774442
Germany, 2002, 18774444
EOD

mySelection = "Afghanistan"
myFilter(n) = strcol(n) eq mySelection ? $3 : NaN

set format y "%.0f"
set key top left
set xtics 1

plot $Data u 2:(myFilter(1)) w lp pt 7 title mySelection

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]